# Git hook not running in Docker on Windows system

Tags: bash, git, docker, git-bash, githooks

We've got this script we must run everytime there's a Git checkout to perform database migrations. So we added it in a **.git/hooks/post-checkout** file:

```
docker exec -it my-container php db/migrate.php status pending
```

After running a `git checkout <BRANCH>` from a Git-Bash terminal, this caused this error:

> **error: cannot spawn .git/hooks/post-checkout: No such file or
> directory**

and after some research, I found that I had to prepend the **SHEBANG** to the beginning of the file, like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
docker exec -it casfid-enterticket-src-1 php db/migrate.php status pending
```

and also make sure that the file was saved as UTF-8. It was previously saved as UTF-16 LE.
Then I got this other error on a `git checkout`:

> **the input device is not a TTY.  If you are using mintty, try prefixing
> the command with 'winpty'**

So googling it I found out that I had to prefix the command with winpty. Then again, the post-checkout hook file:

```
#!/bin/sh
winpty docker exec -it casfid-enterticket-src-1 php db/migrate.php status pending
```

And now I'm stumbling with this new error:

> **stdin is not a tty**

I'm not sure what to do next. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you really need `-it`?

Comment: @Biffen: You're right! I removed those options and the wimpty prepended, and now it works. Thank you! If you may answer it I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: After removing `-it`, you may not need `winpty` any more.